# KDE 5.28 scroll wheel reversing does not work anymore

Tags: kde, mouse, scrolling, plasma5

I did a clean install of Debian 9 stretch with Plasma desktop (KDE 5.28), but migrated my old `/home/philipp`. The KDE settings were not migrated, as it seems, so I chose my settings anew.

One option that doesn't seem to work anymore is reversing the scroll direction of the mouse wheel: No matter whether I check that box or not, the window content scrolls up when I move the wheel down (legacy behaviour).

Does the check box no longer function in that version of KDE? Would this be caused by the migration of my home directory?

Comment: If you can, create a new account without the migratory ballast, and login to that account after a hard reboot. If under that account the check box works, and your mouse reverses, you know that there is something left in your (KDE) config files that causes this.

Comment: Good suggestion. I tried and found the same thing is for a newly created user.